# how do i validate unique mobile number in the seller model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I am trying to validate mobileno(unique) of model seller.
but it giving me error and not doing desired task.
What should I do so that uniqueness of mobileno is checked in the forms?
Following is my model.py:

```
    class Seller(models.Model):
    mobilenno = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, unique=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    name = models.CharField( max_length=64)
  #  city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    phoneno = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

and form.py

```
class SellerRegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    mobileno1 = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30)),
                                  max_digits=10, decimal_places=0,label=_("Mobile Number"))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30, render_value=False)),
                                label=_("Password"))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30, render_value=False)),
                                label=_("Password (again)"))
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30)),
                                 label=_("Seller Name"))
    address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30)),
                                 label=_("Seller Address"))
    phoneno = forms.DecimalField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(required=True, max_length=30)),
                                 max_digits=10, decimal_places=0, label=_("Phone Number"))

    def clean_mobileno1(self):

        try:
            Seller.objects.get(mobileno=self.cleaned_data['mobileno1'])
        except Seller.DoesNotExist:
            return self.cleaned_data['mobileno1']
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("The mobilenumber already exists. Please try another one."))

    def clean(self):
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields did not match."))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
def seller_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SellerRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Seller.objects.create(
                mobilenno=form.cleaned_data['mobileno1'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                name=form.cleaned_data['name'],
                address=form.cleaned_data['address'],
                phoneno=form.cleaned_data['phoneno']
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/success/')
    else:
        form = SellerRegistrationForm()

    return render(request,'registration/register.html', {'form': form })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what error you're getting, so I'm not sure where the error is, but `clean_mobileno1` looks like a good candidate. Check naming consistency between `mobilenno` and `mobileno1`.

The logic in that function is hard to follow, you try to catch an exception for the "normal" use case, and then raise an exception if you don't catch the first one, that seems counter intuitive. Also, you're doing a check on unicity in python, when that should really be pushed to the database (`unique=True` in your field definition should enforce that for you).

I would suggest you use https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field for phone numbers, instead of `Decimal`. You'll get actual phone number validation, and a bunch of very useful phone specific functions. the backend is based on Android's phone-number library, so it tends to stay up-to-date.

Your model becomes:

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

class Seller(models.Model):
    mobileno = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    ...
```

Also, you should probably use a `ModelForm` for your form:

```
class SellerRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Seller

    ...
```

Comment: Can i use character field for storing mobile no with regular expression

Comment: i want to set the field default to 10 digits/characters

Comment: Obviously you can, but why reinvent the wheel, unless your use case is not covered by something that has been around for a while and has proven to work?